# Range when two piecewise functions are composed

Tags: functions

$$f(x):=\begin{cases} [x]         &   -2≤ x ≤ -1 \\
           |x| +1    &   -1≤ x ≤ 2 \end{cases}$$

$$ g(x):=\begin{cases} [x]         &   -π ≤ x ≤ 0 \\
            \sin(x)     &  \phantom{+}0 ≤ x ≤ π \end{cases}$$

Range of $g\circ f(x)$      ( $[x]$ represent greater integer function).

In this question I draw the operator diagram and find the range of individual composite function . I want to know that I have to take union or intersection of the range.

Comment: Your title doesn't mirror the question : it should be something like "Range of the composition of two functions"

Comment: In general, the range of the compostion is neither the intersection, nor the union of the ranges. It is, however, a subset of the range of the last function in the compostion (in your case $g$).

Comment: $f(x)$'s range will be domain for $g(x)$ and using that domain get the range for $g(x)$ , and if range of $f(x)$ lies outside domain of $g(x)$ $g(f(x))$ won't be defined. i would suggest analyze this using graph to get better feel

Comment: I want to know what I should do to two  answer which are coming from the given equation .

Answer (score 1):

The range of $f$ consists of the two points $-2,-1$ and the interval $[1,3]$. That lies entirely within the domain of $g$. Hence the range of $g\circ f$ consists of the two points $-2,-1$ and the interval $[k,1]$ where $k=\sin3\approx0.1411$.